# How can I mirror an object relative to a chosen point, in 3D space?

Tags: modeling

So all of Blender's mirror functions are axis mirroring.

I only know point mirroring / point reflexion from math in 2D. In 2D it's equal to a rotation of 180° around a chosen point.

Is there any way to do it in blender in 3D? Is point reflexion even possible in 3D?

EDIT: After putting more thought into this, it seems I'd need to mirror each point on the closest point on a surface similar to the object itself.

EDIT2: I played around with some python and vector math, but the results where horrible, so to say. It seems that this is not (easily) possible, except when splitting the mesh into several objects.

**Top: standard mirroring**

**Bottom: Imagined point reflexion (made manually)**
[image: Top: standard mirroring Bottom: Imagined point reflexion (made manually)]

Comment: I'd say that mirroring means rotating object on 180d. around chosen point so what is done with the top mesh on the image. Anyway, it may be worth trying to use **Array** modifier to "mirror" it (actually repeat) as you showed in the bottom part of the image. Note that object's origin should be placed accordingly (just like for nearly any modifier).

Comment: The bottom one isn't just repeated. Look closer. Bottom-left: smallest part on the right side. Bottom-right: smallest part on the left side.

Comment: Yes, they differ. It seems it's not the best angle of view on the screenshot for that so to see the difference.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that.

Comment: Of course point reflection is possible to do, I don't think anyone has implemented any tools to do it in blender yet.

Comment: afaik, mirroring is not 180° rotation around chosen point...

Comment: @m.ardito Point reflexion is different to axis reflexion. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_reflection

Comment: It does make sense in 3D, however, it's kinda different: "Geometrically in 3D it amounts to rotation about an axis through P by an angle of 180°, combined with reflection in the plane through P which is perpendicular to the axis; the result does not depend on the orientation (in the other sense) of the axis."

Answer (score 2):

Blender allows you to manipulate center points instead of the whole objects.

Set **Manipulate Center Points**, then mirror the objects: the geometry will not change.

**CAVEAT:** Since it will manipulate individual origins, you have to separate all the components of your model before mirroring.

[image: manipulate center points]

If you want to "reverse" the order of the object, set Pivot Center to Bounding Box Center, then mirror the objects along the desired axis.

[image: Before mirroring pivot center relative to Bounding Box Center]

[image: After mirroring pivot center relative to Bounding Box Center]

#### Shortcuts for these examples

Toggle Manipulate Center Points: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>

Set Pivot Center to Bounding Box Center : <kbd>,</kbd>

Set Pivot Center to 3D Cursor : <kbd>.</kbd>

Mirror along X-Axis: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>

Comment: This comes closest yet, still I need to split my mesh into several objects. Well, it's probably not possible to do.

Comment: Try to split by Loose Parts (edit mode > P > By loose parts): it will separate the mesh in its unconnected parts

Comment: Yeah, that works. But I'd wanted it for a closed surface, this is where it would come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what you want to achieve, but if you wish to mirror a mesh respect a different axis then global X, Y or Z, you can use the "mirror object" option of the "mirror" modifier, specifying (eg) a plane (place it in the scene as if its XY surface was a real, infinite mirror): the Z axis of the plane will be the "direction" of the mirroring.

eg:

[image]